# Set A variable from other Variable in a class without function

Tags: php, oop

I started using classes in PHP, and I have the following code:

```
class webConfig
{
  public $SALT1 = "3525";
  public $SALT2 = "2341";
  public $SALT3 = $SALT1.$SALT2;
}
```

But this gives me 500 Internal Server Error, which means that I am doing something wrong.

Is there any way of doing this without using any function, including construct?

This does not work aswell:

```
class webConfig
{
  public $SALT1 = "3525";
  public $SALT2 = "2341";
  public $SALT3 = $this->SALT1.$this->SALT2;
}
```

Comment: Once defined a class variable is accessed using `$this->variable_name`

Comment: this does not work aswell.

Comment: I know, but that was the first mistake. You will have to do things like this in a constructor function, which you for some reason don't want to use.

Comment: @PHPLover why not functions?

Comment: So there is no other way of defining a variable to another variables value, without using constructor function? If yes, than what is the reason?

Comment: No functions, because it's a very simple problem, and don't understand, why this is impossible to achieve.

Comment: A constructor function runs automatically when creating an instance, why is that a bother?

Comment: Because I have to declare the variable and then set it in Construct, which is double work... And that's why I was thinking doing it without it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **In PHP; Expressions are not allowed as Default Values of any Property.** For this reason, PHP is simply saying that you should not even imagine doing that in the first place. 
> But, fortunately then; this is why you have the Constructor Method — *to help you initialize some class Properties, assign Default values to Member Properties using Expression
>  (like in your case), etc....*  Using a Constructor, your class could look like the Snippet below and it is expected to work as well:

```
<?php
    class webConfig {
      public $SALT1 = "3525";
      public $SALT2 = "2341";          
      public $SALT3;

      public function __construct(){
          // SET THE VALUE $SALT3 HERE INSTEAD 
          $this->SALT3 = $this->SALT1 . $this->SALT2;
      }
    }
```

> Alternatively; you may even initialize all the Properties of the Class within the Constructor like so:

```
<?php
    class webConfig {
      public $SALT1;    //<== NOTICE THAT THIS PROPERTY IS NOT INITIALIZED.
      public $SALT2;    //<== NOTICE THAT THIS PROPERTY IS NOT INITIALIZED.        
      public $SALT3;    //<== NOTICE THAT THIS PROPERTY IS NOT INITIALIZED.

      public function __construct(){
          $this->SALT1 = "3525";
          $this->SALT2 = "2341"; 
          $this->SALT3 = $this->SALT1 . $this->SALT2;  //<== YET AGAIN; SET THE VALUE 
                                                       //<== OF $SALT3 LIKE BEFORE
      }
    }
```

Comment: @RST   ***"So there is no other way of defining a variable to another variables value, without using constructor function?*** **If yes, than what is the reason?"** Now, He knows the Reason so, whether it's double-work or not, he may have to accept the requirements of the Language.....

Comment: This answer had already been suggested but dismissed because of the double work. That is why I asked? There is no need to answer for him.